# In sinatra if I want add a method to String class, where should I put these code?

Tags: sinatra

```
class String
  def show(word)
    word
  end
end
```

if I want to add this method in Sinatra, I first try to add to helper code, but it gave me a no method error, what is the best way to do this

Comment: you should be able to put it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't add it inside any helpers as `helpers ... do` is a method in itself.

What you should do is create an `ext` directory in your project root, add a file called `string.rb` and put your code inside that.

Then in your `app.rb`, add `require './ext/string.rb'`

This would be a simplistic way to go about it, but there are many other ways to structure your code.

EDIT:

As per Matt's response below, you should call your directory `core_ext` instead of `ext`

Comment: `ext` might not be the best name, as it is used for extensions (i.e. C or Java code). I've seen `core_ext` used in a few places (Rails uses it for instance), which might be a better bet.

Comment: Matt, you are right - thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer accordingly.